# Inconsistent results for a function related to android screen size and dimensions

Tags: android, kotlin

I was creating a new android app that has a particular feature in a one of the screens, which is generating an image to a random spot in the screen, I used a class as a helper to return screen dimensions:

```
private val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics by lazy {
    Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
}

// Returns boundary of the screen in pixels (px).
val screenRectPx: Rect get() = displayMetrics.run { Rect(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels) }

// Returns boundary of the screen in density independent pixels (dp).
val screenRectDp: RectF get() = screenRectPx.run { RectF(0f, 0f, right.px2dp, bottom.px2dp) }

// Converts any given number from pixels (px) into density independent pixels (dp).
val Number.px2dp: Float get() = this.toFloat() / displayMetrics.density
```

Then I have created a function in the fragment (I call this function 30 times every time I click the image):

```
private fun generateNewPosition(){

    val startMarginLimit: Int = widthDp.toInt() - 100
    val topMarginLimit: Int = heightDp.toInt() - 340

    val startMarginRandom = (0 until startMarginLimit).random()
    val topMarginRandom = (0 until topMarginLimit).random()

    val startMarginInDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        startMarginRandom.toFloat(),
        resources.displayMetrics
    ).toInt()

    val topMarginInDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        topMarginRandom.toFloat(),
        resources.displayMetrics
    ).toInt()


    val linearLayoutParams = target.getLayoutParams() as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    linearLayoutParams.setMargins(startMarginInDp, topMarginInDp, 0, 0)
    target.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams)

}
```

The width and height of the image itself inside xml is 90dp, anyway it worked as expected while I was debugging on two phones and an emulator, all works fine, but I published the app on google play store and I downloaded it from two other phones one of them exactly like the one I used to debug and the function didn't work as expected, the image kept generating a random spots vertically, but horizontally is the same, it always at the edge of the screen and even after clicking it for the 30th time (which should finally set visibility to this image to gone) the app crashes, I also tried to uninstall from the phone I was using to debug the app (uninstalled the debug version) and install it from google play store and it works just fine and no crashes, what could cause these behaviors?

Comment: What caused the crash?

Comment: I can't see the reason for the crash as it's not debug version, but crash happens when the image visibility is gone

Comment: You said that it's happening on a Google Play release? If so then you can view the stack traces in the console.

Comment: Yes in the google play release, as it's fairly new, the console didn't generate it yet, but maybe if I know why the function itself didn't work as expected I can expect the bug too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was related to phone's language, if the language is rtl the problem shows, as the layout reversed, so the startMargin keep applying it self to the edge (where the image initially generated in right), and I fixed the problem by setting the layout direction to ltr by using:

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a sensible solution unless you're sure that you don't want to cater to RTL scripts. This is really just a workaround instead of spending a small amount of time fixing your logic for both directions.

Comment: I'm just wanted to highlight the problem and what was causing it, not really want to say how it was solved, I know I could've fixed it for both directions, but for my app (problem) it's enough for one direction because it doesn't matter whether it's actually RTL or LTR.